# Calling method in Master page from User control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, toastr

I am building a web forms application where I user the JS lib Toastr for displaying messages to the user.
This works great ...for most parts. 
My application is designed like this

Master -
Nested Master -
Page -
User Control

I Have implemented the calling to Toastr in Master:

```
public void ShowToastr(Page page, string message, string title, string type = "info")
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "toastr_message",
        $"toastr.{type.ToLower()}('{message}', '{title}');", addScriptTags: true);
}
```

I have virtual path set in every master and content page:

Admin.master file

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Areas/Shared/Site.Master" %>
```

SystemSettings.aspx page

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Areas/Administration/Admin.Master" %>
```

The UserCntrol is on SystemSettings.aspx page

Then I call the SiteMaster method like this from User Control

```
((SystemSettings)this.Page).Master.Master.ShowToastr(this.Page, "Property successfully updated.", "Success", $"{nameof(ToastrTypeEnum.Success)}");
```

This works great....until I put the User Control on a different page (want to be able to use controls in more then one place. .

I have tried several things after a search on the internet. .

```
(this.Page.Master as SiteMaster)?.ShowToastr(this.Page, "Property successfully updated.", "Success", $"{nameof(ToastrTypeEnum.Success)}");
```

also

```
SiteMaster _m = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;


_m.ShowToastr(this.Page, "Unable to save new property", "Error", $"{nameof(ToastrTypeEnum.Error)}");
```

Anyone with a suggestion on how to resolve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this fixes your issue because the resulting error of using the Control elsewhere is not in your question.
But why not make `ShowToastr` a static method in a separate class and not the Master? That way you do not have to send the `Page` to the method and/or cast the Master.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void howToastr(string message, string title, string type = "info")
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "toastr_message", $"toastr.{type.ToLower()}('{message}', '{title}');", addScriptTags: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the job :) 

I put a static helper class in my Domain based project and call it "InfoDisplay.DisplayMessage("Test message !!!", "Test title", nameof(ToastrTypeEnum.Error)); " Workes like a charm